# How do I Pass Asp.Net MVC ViewData to vue.js data object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am using vue.js in lieu of Asp.Net MVC templating and 
below is the code.

```
@model Manage.Models.Commands.Category.UpdateCategoryViewModel

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { Category` = Model, @class = "edit" }))
{
<div id="categoriesUpdate">
<div class="modal-content"> 
<div class="modal-header">
<h2>Edit Category</h2>
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">&#xE5C9;</i></button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body table-responsive" id="modal-query">
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
} 

<table class="table">
<colgroup>
<col class="col-half" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TenantId)
<tr>
    <td>Category Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CategoryName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" v-bind:value="model.CategoryName"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var app = new Vue({
el: '#categoriesUpdate',
data: {
model: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
errors3: @ViewData.ModelState

}
});
});

</script>
```

I want to pass the ViewData errors to the vue.js data object, so that I can use the vue.js loop rendering

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1))
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

I have tried all the below options

1. 2. validations: @ViewData.ModelState.Where(n => n.Value.Errors.Count >
      0).ToList(),

      2. errors: Json.Encode(@ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors));
      3. errors1: Json.Stringify(@ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)),
         4.errors2: Json.Stringify(@ViewData.ModelState.ToList()[0]),
         5.errors3: Json.Stringify(@ViewData.ModelState.ToList()[0].ToString()),
      4. errors3: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData))